# Submitting form with Dictionary model gets Controller name and Action name values-

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `form` that has a `Dictionary<string, object>` `Model`, When i submit the form values passed are `Controller` name and `Action` name. Why is this happening? Thank you in advance.[image]

Here's my code:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Form(int id)
{
    var model = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    model.Add("FullName", "Test");
    model.Add("ContactNumber", "09973070562");

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Dictionary<string, string> test)
{
    return View("form", test);
}
```

Form:

```
@model Dictionary<string, object>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Form";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<legend>Order</legend>
<br />
@using (@Html.BeginForm("save", "module", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>@m.Key</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="@m.Key" value="@m.Value">
        </div>
    }
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
}
```

Comment: Full code please, as text not pictures

Comment: Just use `this.Request.Form`.

Comment: You cannot use a `Dictionary<String,String>` to accept HTML `<form>` values because names can have multiple values, but a `Dictionary<String,String>` requires distinct names for each value. Use `IFormCollection ` instead.

Comment: Why aren't you using a strongly-typed viewmodel? That renders your entire question moot and means you won't have any _magic strings_ like `FullName` and `ContactNumber` - also, you might want to remove that phone-number (`099...`) if it's real.

Comment: Thank you sir @Dai i'll just use `IFormCollection` or `Ajax`

Comment: @Dai it is because i'm creating tables and columns dynamically using dynamic sql, so i don't konw what are the specific columns of the tables

Answer (score -1):

you can use `formdata` in javascript.
then send it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("FullName", "Groucho");
formData.append("ContactNumber", 123456); 
 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://hamedhossani.com/Save");
request.send(formData);
```